# How to use Mallet for NER

Tags: nlp, mallet

I'm new to the subject of NLP and requested to perform -named entity recognition- (NER) using Mallet.
I have a text, and I give feature vector for each word in it. I would like to train a model which later on I can test on fresh text file.
My question is how do I create such model, what is the input for the model. I could use some code examples :) 
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Fei Xia at UW wrote a pretty good [MALLET guide](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse454/15wi/papers/mallet_guide.pdf).

You can find an example of programmatic (Java) interaction with MALLET at the bottom of [this page](http://sites.google.com/site/nicoflacco/).

Answer (score 1):

The [MALLET quick start on sequence tagging](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/sequences.php), right on the MALLET home page, describes exactly how to do this if you already have the feature vectors.